# I made a program that will add two numbers only if the first number is greater than the second number and its not comparing

Tags: assembly, x86-16

My problem is that it does not compare whether the first number is greater than the second number.. It only executes the part where I print a string

```
    mov ah,9
    lea dx,str1
    int 21h           ;Write string at DS:DX to standard output

    mov ah,1
    int 21h           ;Read character from standard input into AL
    sub al,30h        ;al = character - '0'
    mov num1,al       ;num = character - '0'

    mov ah,9
    lea dx,str2
    int 21h           ;Write string at DS:DX to standard output

    mov ah,1
    int 21h           ;Read character from standard input into AL

    mov al,2

    cmp num1,al       ;Is num1 greater than 2?
    jg sum            ; yes, goto sum
                      ; no  
    mov ah,9
    lea dx,str3
    int 21h           ;Write string at DS:DX to standard output
    jmp exit


sum:
    add num1,al       ;num1 = num1 + AL = num1 + 2

    mov ah,9
    lea dx,new
    int 21h           ;Write string at DS:DX to standard output

    mov ah,9
    lea dx,num1
    int 21h           ;Write string at DS:DX to standard output
    jmp exit

exit:
```

Comment: I do not see an actual question, I do not know what language you are coding in, and I think the format of your post needs more work.  Please fix these things so we can help you.

Comment: I'm using conditional statement in assembly language..my problem is that it does not not compare whether the first number is greater than the second number..

Comment: Well you've got a `cmp num1,al` `jg sum` in there, so the CPU probably *is* comparing something. However, the instruction before that is `mov al,2` so you are seemingly comparing the value of `num1` with `2`, which doesn't seem to match your description of what you want your code to do (compare first number to second number).

Comment: @GregHewgill - yes, I was expecting another 'sub al,30h'.

Comment: Original source code was extremely bad (bad indenting, no comments at all). I editing it to fix indenting, and added some comments to make it seem slightly more like actual/professional/readable assembly

Answer (score 0):

You have written this

```
cmp num1,al       ;Is num1 greater than 2?
jg sum            ; yes, goto sum
                  ; no
```

You are taking wrong meaning of cmp statement

correct meaning and statement(for this scenerio) is

```
cmp num1,al       ;Is 2 lesser than num1?
    jl sum            ; yes, goto sum
                      ; no
```

I have modified Your code, now it will be like this

```
    org  100h
    jmp start
    str1 dw 'Provide Input',10,13,'$' 
    str2 dw 'Provide another input',10,13,'$' 
    str3 dw 'First is greater',10,13,'$'
    new dw 'Second is greater',10,13,'$'   
    num1 db ?
    start:
    mov ah,9

    lea dx,str1
    int 21h           ;Write string at DS:DX to standard output

    mov ah,1
    int 21h           ;Read character from standard input into AL
    sub al,30h        ;al = character - '0'
    mov num1,al       ;num = character - '0'

    mov ah,9
    lea dx,str2
    int 21h           ;Write string at DS:DX to standard output

    mov ah,1
    int 21h           ;Read character from standard input into AL
    sub al,30h        ;al = character - '0'

    cmp num1,al       ;Is al lesser than num1?
    jl sum            ; yes, goto sum
                      ; no  
    mov ah,9
    lea dx,str3
    int 21h           ;Write string at DS:DX to standard output
    jmp exit


sum:
    add num1,al       ;num1 = num1 + AL = num1 + al

    mov ah,9
    lea dx,new                
    int 21h           ;Write string at DS:DX to standard output

exit:
    MOV AH,4CH 
    INT 21H
```

Now try it in this way first give input 2 than 5, see output. Now run it again and give input as 5 than 2. You will understand more when you run it yourself.